# Add spacing to avoid arrow over label

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\tikzset{%
    block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, node distance=3em, minimum height = 3em,
        minimum width = 3em, align=center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, >=triangle 45]

\draw node [block] (b) {B};
\draw node [block, above left=of b, label=below:Label] (a) {A};
\draw[->](a) |- (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the corresponding image:

[image]

How do I reduce the length/shift the starting point of the arrow so it does not draw above the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! You could give the label a name and connect the label rather than the node.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\tikzset{%
    block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, node distance=3em, minimum height = 3em,
        minimum width = 3em, align=center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, >=triangle 45]

\draw node [block] (b) {B};
\draw node [block, above left=of b, label={[name=aLabel]below:Label}] (a) {A};
\draw[->](aLabel) |- (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution respects all keys that you can set with `every label`. Adding an explicit extra node does not.

Comment: This is even better as it keeps the label definition at the actual node to which it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\tikzset{%
    block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, node distance=3em, minimum height = 3em,
        minimum width = 3em, align=center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, >=triangle 45]

\draw node [block] (b) {B};
\draw node [block, above left=of b] (a) {A};
\draw (a.south) node [below] (a2) {Label};
\draw[->](a2.south) |- (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! I've just found \draw[->] ([yshift=-1.3em]a.south) |- (b)
But your solution is cleaner as one doesn't have to fiddle around with finding a nice shift.